# Minify JavaScript code through C# - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, minify

I'm trying to write a templated user control that get's as a template the js code from the user,

And minifies it on the fly (OnInit), and actually prints the minified JS.

That means that I need a code that receives a string, and returns a string.

All I found untill know are programs that uses the input \ output from the hard-drive, something that I can't allow.

Is there any C# Libraries relevant to my issue \ need ?

Thanks all.

EDIT:

When I say minify, I just meen removing comments, spaces and obfuscation.

Comment: Maybe related http://stackoverflow.com/q/4234213/340760

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cached JavaScript minification on the fly – ASP.NET and HttpHandler](http://robertpohl.blogspot.com/2009/03/cached-javascript-minification-on-fly.html)

Answer (score 0):

This was answered over in another answer about a year later and it's a bit more elegant:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8573261/128795