# Creating and minifying JavaScript dynamically in ASP.NET MVC server-side code

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-bundling

I am using a ASP.NET route (to intercept the call to the .js) and controller to generate some JS I want to use on my client. The reason I'm doing this is so as to not have to duplicate id's or constants on the client. Here's the output of my JS:

```
app.serviceRootURL = 'http://localhost:65211/';  // set in my web.config
app.ajaxResponseStatuses = [
    { "status":"Success", "id":0 },              // set in my C# DTO
    { "status":"Failure", "id":1 },
];
```

First of all, I am not sure if this is the best approach, so other suggestions to doing this would be beneficial.

More importantly though, I'm wondering how I can bundle and minify this. As I understand it, even if I could minify the JS at compile or run-time, minification will change the names of my variables. So in the above JS, `app.ajaxResponseStatuses` could get changed to `a.bc`, and then in the actual JS files where I'm trying to access that variable, they could be looking for `x.yz`.

1. Can I minify this code and get it to the server?
2. Will I still be able to use the above properties in other minified files?
3. (bonus points) Is this a good aproach to pass server-side-only values to be used on the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Part 1

If you are generating the js at runtime, bundling isn't possible (at least not efficiently). You would have to create a new bundle for every request which isn't terribly quick. Plus, you wouldn't be able to cache the regular, constant script bundle.

**EDIT:** While bundling server-generated js isn't practical, rendering the values into a script tag in the page can achieve the same benefit of bundling, fewer HTTP calls. See the edit in Part 3 for more.

Minifying the server generated js however, is totally possible. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567070/is-there-a-net-library-for-minifying-javascript) should have the answer you're looking for. *However*, I'd recommend you cache this on the server if possible, as the minification process itself could take longer than simply sending down the extra bits.

#### Part 2

In most minifiers, global variables (those accessible on the `window` object) are skipped during the name mangling. With the same respect, variables that are accessed in other files that are not defined within that file are not renamed.

For example, if you have the following file...

```
// outside of a closure, so globally accessible
var foo = 1;

function bar() {
  // within a closure, and defined with `var`, not globally accessible
  var bar;

  // reference to variable declared in another file
  baz = null;
}
```

it would be minified as follows (with whitespace included for readability

```
var foo = 1;

function bar() {
  var b;

  baz = null;
}
```

This is one reason it is important to always declare your variables using the `var` keyword, otherwise they are assumed to be references to global variables and will not be minified.

Also, JSON (*not Javascript object literals!!!*) will never be distorted by minifiers, because it consists of string literals for all keys, and all values that aren't of another literal type.

#### Part 3

Not a bad way, and at my job we do use this approach. For small files though, or simple config values, we have transitioned to rendering server values in a script tag using ASP.NET in the actual view. i.e.

*Default.aspx*

```
<script> window.globals = <%= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new AppGlobals(currentUser)) %>; </script>
```

We rip this out into a code behind, but the premise is the same.

**EDIT**:

#### Server-Generated JS (at it's own uri)

- Pros

  - Cacheable by browser (if fresh values aren't needed on every request)
- Cons

  - Extra round trip
- Use when:

  - Your generated files are large, but rarely change or are the same for multiple users. These scripts can be treated the same as other static assets. To give an example, we serve a js file containing all the text in our app for localization purposes. We can serve a different js file based on the language set in the user's settings, but these values only change once at most with every release, so we can set aggressive cache headers and use a hash in the uri, along with a query string for the locale, to leverage browser caching and download each language file only once per client. Plus, if this file is going to be the same for every user accessing the same uri, you can cache it at the web server (IIS, Apache, etc.).
    Ex: `/api/language.v1-0-0.js?locale=en`
  - Your js is independent from the rest of your app and not having it won't delay rendering. In this case, you can add the `async` attribute to your script tag, and this file will be downloaded asynchronously and executed when it is received without preventing the execution of other javascript.

#### Server-Rendered JS (within the page in a `script` tag)

- Pros

  - No extra HTTP calls
- Cons

  - Can add extra weight to your HTML, which may not be cacheable or minified depending on your circumstances
- Use when:

  - Your values change often. The weight added to the page should be negligible unless you have a huge number of values (in that case, you might consider splitting them up and adding API endpoints for these values, and only getting them when you need them). With this, you can cut out the extra HTTP call as the js is injected into a script tag on a page the user would already have to retrieve.

#### But...

Don't waste too much time worrying about it. The differences in these two approaches is almost always negligible. If it becomes a problem, try both and use the better option for your case.

Comment: Cheers for your detailed response. I like the idea of having a dedicated aspx script page, however won't implement this until my script gets sufficiently complex to benefit from it. I'm not a fan of Razor syntax, so shy away from it when I can. Good to know about global variables not being minified, seems obvious now that I know.

Comment: Glad I could be of help. I can definitely vouch for dislike of Razor; it's far too noisy for my taste. With that being said, there are some trade-offs that should be considered with server-side rendering vs server generated js. I'll update my answer to include some of these.